# What was the population of the Parthian Empire around (AD) 1 CE?

Tags: persia, population

What was the population of the [Parthian Empire](https://www.worldhistorymaps.info/images/Parthia_001ad.jpg) (and its vassals) around (AD) 1 CE?

I've found several estimates ranging from 8 to 30 million. However, I desire a more narrow estimate (±5 million). I appreciate your input.

Comment: They didn't have a census - so all figures are guestimates based on assumptions.  Provide us with the assumptions you want made and not made; and only then can a figure consistent with those assumptions be provided.

Comment: From Wikipedia's [Parthian empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthian_Empire): "The size of the Parthian army is unknown, *as is the size of the empire's overall population*." You could try asking for estimates in academic sources but, as your own research seems to show, you're unlikely to find a consensus.

Comment: Well, this Wikipedia article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_by_population_in_1_AD) gives us an estimation of 8 million; however, I wasn't able to find the source.

Comment: Hi. Please list the examples and cite your sources.

Comment: Well, this Wikipedia article ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_by_population_in_1_AD) gives us an estimation of 8 million; however, I wasn't able to find the source. AND Assumptions: "We can compare it to other similarity sized empires at different times, such as the Persian Empire. Under the rule of Cyrus, the population was an estimated 17 to 35 million people."

Comment: Where did you find those estimates?  I don't think anyone wants to waste time providing y ou an estimate you already have.  Analysis of the sources you've already consulted can help to refine the precision of the estimates.

Comment: - Wikipedia (Probably McEvedy & Jones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_by_population_in_1_AD)
 - https://www.worldhistorymaps.info/images/Parthia_001ad.jpg
 - Morris, Ian; Scheidel, Walter (2009). The Dynamics of Ancient Empires: State Power from Assyria to Byzantium. Oxford University Press. p. 77. ISBN 978-0-19-975834-0. (Assumption!): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achaemenid_Empire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Segal's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%27s_law): A man with a watch knows what time it is. A man with two watches is never sure.

---

[image]

Well, personally I like that 8 million number you have. However ...

This is a basic issue a lot of people seem to have with ancient population numbers. They want to know them with modern Census precision, and that information simply is not available. There are many different ways of estimating, and many different people doing it, and they all come up with different numbers. This is where Segal's Law comes in: We don't and can't know the number *exactly*, and the fact that we have such wildly varying numbers is showing you just how uncertain all the numbers are.

That doesn't mean we can't analyze the quality of the numbers we've got, of course. Any more than all watches being out of sync means there's no point in wearing one.

A simple person can pick one watch and stick with it. For myself, I like to use [McEvedy & Jones](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/624253.Atlas_of_World_Population_History)' Atlas of World Population history. Their numbers tend to run low, but they are *comprehensive* for the entire world and its entire history, so its at least consistent, and suitable for showing population change over time.

For the main parts of the Archameid Empire at 1 AD they show:

- 4 million for Persia
- 1 million for Iraq
- 2 million for Afghanistan

We'll be generous and give them perhaps another 1 million for all the other little bits they have, which would bring our rough estimate up to about **8 million** (the same as your lower number, if it isn't in fact the source of your lower number).

But if you want a *certain* number down to something like 20% precision?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the extra million cover the northwest regions of the Indian subcontinent (parts of modern Pakistan and northwestern India)? https://www.worldhistorymaps.info/images/Parthia_001ad.jpg

Comment: @RookieAlina - I'd have to say it doesn't. Unfortunately M&J treat India, Pakistan, and Bangladesh as a unit (probably a quirk from them growing up as Imperial Era Brits I'd guess). For that date they place the entire unit at 35 million, 2/3rds of which would have been living the in the Ganges basin (probably most of the rest in the Indus).

Comment: To make things more interesting, I'm actually having a lot of trouble finding good info on who owned what on the Indus Valley end of Parthia at that time. Could have been Parthians themselves, could have been some [Indo-Greeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strato_II), could have been [Indo-Sythians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Scythians). Its tempting to think the situation there may have been just as confusing for the areas' residents at the time.

Comment: ...according to Mr. McEvedy's Atlas of ancient history, there was a Saka (Indo-Scythian) kingdom in control of the lower Indus around 44BC. The Surens running the eastern half of the Parthian Empire (including some of the upper Indus valley) broke up their power, but didn't take over their territory. By his next map at 14AD, he doesn't venture a guess as to who's running that area.

Comment: Thank you, you've just answered a different question I had ("2/3rds of which would have been living the in the Ganges basin"). You see, I'm trying to make a more "reliable" chart/list of "List of states by population in 1 AD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_by_population_in_1_AD) for my presentation.
So far I've been able to pinpoint all the states/empires I want to have on that list. But I'm struggling with the numbers here.

Comment: The list: Roman Empire (I have the numbers), Han Empire ("), Parthian Empire ( I have the numbers but I just don't belived them - the numbers seem to be really low in my opinion), Xiongnu Empire ( I have the numbers, they also seem to be quite low but I think that overall they are reasonable) and maybe the Dacian Kingdom (").

Comment: Now here enters "The Indian Subcontinent"... As you've mentioned, M&J give us a fairly low estimate (34 million), whereas others (Maddison, Clark, Biraben, Durand,) give us 75/70/46/75 respectively (60 million on avarage). According to my research (maps, books, wikipedia and other articles) the largest "organized political communities" at that time where:  Satavahana Empire, Mahameghavahana Empire, Sakas (Indo-Scythian Kingdom), Kushans (not the "Kushan Empire", yet)*, Indo-Parthians (vassals of the Parthian Empire) and the Indo-Greek Kingdom.

Comment: However, I have no idea how to distribute the 60 million population among them. But if your statement ("2/3rds of which would have been living the in the Ganges basin") is true (could you please source that), things are suddenly much more easier.

Comment: McEvedy and Jones: "By 500bc the subcontinental total had reached 25m, of whom 15m lived in the Ganges basin; by 200bc, when the Guptas of Bihar had put together the first major Indian empire, the figures were30m and20m." (and yes, I realize that bit about the Guptas is probably wrong)

Comment: That indeed is confusing. I always thought that M&J are a reliable source (people cite them quite often). "by 200bc, when the Guptas of Bihar" could be fixed to "by 200bc, when the Mauryas of Pataliputra" or it could be "by AD 200, when the Guptas of Bihar" but quite frankly, I think I'm just stretching it, neither of those "solution" make sense. So to what "Guptas of Biha" are they referring to?

Comment: Well, the're also an old source. 1975 is nearly half a century gone now. So it could be some peeps back then thought the dating worked out that way. Or it could just be a flat-out error. The more you learn about history, the more such errors you notice in your sources. Reference final graphic.